# libgdx sprite is disorted when scaling and rotating

Tags: libgdx, rotation, sprite, scale, scaling

I want to rotate and scale my Sprite but it looks disorted:
[image: Disorted Sprite]

This is my render method:

```
 public void renderMain(float delta){
        batch.begin();
        GameScreenShipUpdater.getTexture(yourship).setPosition(yourship.getRectangle().x, yourship.getRectangle().y);
        GameScreenShipUpdater.getTexture(yourship).setSize(25f, 10f);
        GameScreenShipUpdater.getTexture(yourship).setOriginCenter();
        GameScreenShipUpdater.getTexture(yourship).setRotation(130f);
        GameScreenShipUpdater.getTexture(yourship).draw(batch);

        batch.end();

    }
```

How can I fix this? This is how the Sprite looks without rotating:
[image: not rotated]

Comment: The distortion is from you calling `setSize(25f, 10f)`, not from the rotation.

Comment: But I want the Sprite's size to increase. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Use parameters that maintain the same aspect ratio as the original sprite, or use the `setScale` method instead, passing in only one parameter.

Comment: Actually I do see very faint distortion across the scene, probably affecting both of your screen shots. The aspect ratio of your camera viewport must be slightly taller than that of the window.

Comment: Thank you! That's because I'm resizing the window so it looks good on desktop and on Android. If I'd keep the size of the Sprite then it would look crushed on Android because the width is smaller. So I wanted to increase the width of the  Sprite.

Comment: Use an ExtendViewport (or FillViewport if glutton for punishment) instead of a StretchViewport/ScreenViewport/FixedViewport so that there is no distortion on any shape of screen. You can read about viewports in the LibGDX documentation.

Comment: Thanks! But if I use an ExtendView parts of the viewport are being cut off. Isn't there a way so I can only scale the width correctly?

Comment: ExtendViewport doesn't cut off...it adds extra. Make sure you read the documentation carefully.

Comment: But if it adds extra and I want to draw a texture on the edge of the viewport, the coordinates will change. How should I get the right coordinates then?

Comment: Bottom left corner of visible area is camera position minus half of camera viewport width and height. Similar for other three corners. If you want the bottom left to always be (0, 0) then move the camera to (camera.viewportWidth/2, camera.viewportHeight/2). But for a fixed camera game I would think you'd want to keep it centered. It really depends on what style of game you're making and what is acceptable to crop, etc.

Comment: See first reply here: http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=19529